# Stick to 1-6-11 channels or use others?

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, wireless-router

My apartment uses one router and multiples access points with channels 2, 4, 7 and 9. I have a feeling this is the reason there's so much interference that the internet is really bad. Two neighbours around us use channel 1 and 11.

I went over some threads here and other links online and contradicting advice was observed. Some say it's best to stick to 1-6-11 (as cisco study shows), and others say to move away for less interference. Now I'm just confused, as I want to advice the IT guy to change the channels for the whole apartment and keep it under one channel, but I don't want to ask for that without good knowledge of what I'm saying.

So can someone tell me what is the most recent advisable method to follow ?

[image]

Comment: Without getting into to much detail about the size of your apartment, is it really big enough to warrant **four** APs?  One or two should more than cover anything under 2 stories/2000 sq ft.

Comment: @Jason it's a five story building.

Answer (score 1):

The apartment complex might be right - while 1-6-11 will eliminate interference between 3 access points, in cases where it's too crowded to avoid overlap between multiple strong signals on a three channel configuration,  it can be better to use 2-4-7-9 such that more channels are available and impact of the channel overlap is minimized. My understanding is that for 802.11g overlap impacts the channel above and below heavily, and 2 channels away slightly.

Ideally, the overlap is controlled not just by channel selection but also by limiting power levels, and using directional antennas to minimize the interference from densely packed APs.

If overlap is unavoidable due to too high of a density of access points, you want as little of it as possible - in other words, placing the channels in use closer together and accepting that some interference from channel overlap is inevitable - for example:

- 3 access points - 1-6-11 (no overlap - ideal setup)
- 4 access points - 2-4-7-9 (one channel overlap)
- 5-6 access points - 1-3-5-7-9-11 (significant overlap, but none share same center frequency, so should still be stable but degraded.).

All setups but the 1-6-11 arrangement interfere with each other, but the interference from the other channel plans will be significantly less than the impact of having multiple access points on exactly the same channel.

Unfortunately, this is probably all moot - nothing forces neighbors and apartment managers to choose channels cooperatively or rationally, so getting this fixed is probably a losing battle - a first world "tragedy of the commons" under which everyone insisting on what is ideal for them results in something that's ruined for everyone.

Your best bet for dodging the interference will be to move anything you can into the 5ghz band, which opens up more channels (and has less structural penetration. For things that have to stay on the 2.4Ghz band in such a heavily saturated environment, take the least densely packed channel even if it has overlap with adjacent channels, Directional antennas on your access point/router may also improve your signal and help to overcome interference.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive reply. @jim G. mentioned that a 1-6-11 looped install would actually work ? What do you think ? It's the other answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a good signal for yourself, use channel 1 on your router.  There are only three other APs in range that overlap channel 1, so there wouldn't be a ton of interference.

That's the quickest fix without having to involve apartment management.

EDIT:  I just re-read your question.  Does the apartment complex supply the wifi on channels 2, 4, 7, and 9?  In that case the answer is different.  They should use 1, 6, and 11, then re-use one of the channels on the two APs that are furthest apart.

So for example, if the was an AP on each floor, put the first floor on channel 1, second on channel 6, third on channel 11, and the fourth on channel 1 again.

Comment: Thanks for reply and suggestion. Can you check the other answer and let me know what you think ? Your method, which sounds really convenient, is not suggested.